# jQuery Datepicker Beforeshowday - Ajax return array of unavailable dates

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I am trying to get a datepicker to update a array of unavailable dates. The below works if I pass a PHP variable, but the issue I'm having seems to be returning the data for the option correctly (it is throwing a console error of cannot read undefined of 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#MyDate').datepicker({
        minDate: '+2',
        maxDate: new Date(2014, 1, 28),
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',

        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            //var array = ["<?php echo $comma_seperated;?>"];

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data: {
                    action: 'unavail_dates',
                    unavaildates: '2'
                },
                success: function (output) {
                    saveVariable(output);
                }
            });

            function saveVariable(data) {
                array = '"' + data + '"';
                console.log(array);
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date);
                return [array.indexOf(string) == -1];
            }
        },
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
            jQuery(this).change();
        }
    })
```

Note the console log displays the same as the commented var array which works. I am using a function to use the returned values from its corresponding code, but it simply returns a string of comma-separated dates and missing its first and last ". For example, 2013/12/12","2013/12/13","2013/12/14

Comment: The problem is you are not returning any value from `beforeShowDay`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hacky but it works. I had to create a button to call the datepicker from. Any code I tried trying the .click event on the same element seems to not update in time. .deferred , etc. simply didn't fire the datepicker. I was able to get an Ajax then initialize datepicker working inserting the entire code in the HTML onclick"" in the element, but I couldn't reproduce this with `.click`.

Any way, my method:

1. Create a alternative button to fire `(#element).click` from
2. Create the Ajax function to retrieve dates in realtime (it takes about five seconds to apply if you are testing it from another page in realtime).
3. Put datepicker code into a success callback.
4. Fire the `.click` event.

Step 1: HTML of elements:

```
<td><input type="text" id="MyDate" name="MyDate" readonly='true' value="click here" /></td><td><input type="button" id="button" name="button" value="Select date"></td></td>
```

Step 2: Ajax call to find the available dates (I'm using WordPress so the URL is specific to WordPress)

```
AjaxGet = function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'unavail_dates',
            unavaildates: '2'
        },
        success: function (output) {
            dates = jQuery.parseJSON('["'+output+'"]');
            mySuccessCallback( dates );
            console.log ( dates );
        }
    });
};
```

Step 3: mySuccessCallback() function from above code:

```
function mySuccessCallback(dates) {
    array = dates
    jQuery('#MyDate').datepicker({
        minDate: '+2',
        maxDate: new Date(2014, 1,28),
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date);
            return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ];
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            jQuery(this).change();
        }
    }).change(function() {
        if (document.getElementById('date_error_row').style.visibility == 'visible') {
            document.getElementById('date_error_row').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        var postid = '<?php echo esc_js($posted_id); ?>';
        var pdate = jQuery(this).val(); //Select updated value

        jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {action: 'tempsave', postid: postid , postdate: pdate , status: 'waiting'},
            success:function(data){
                jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
            }
        });
        jQuery('#MyDate').datepicker('destroy');
    });
    jQuery('#MyDate').datepicker('show');
}
```

Step 4:

```
jQuery('#button').click(function() {
    AjaxGet();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not returning any value from the `beforeShowDay` method. That method does not allow asynchronous calls.

In your case, in `beforeShowDay`, you are sending an Ajax request and then the method returns an undefined value so all dates will be considered as valid then later the Ajax request is completed and `saveVariable` method gets called, but it does not have any effect on the value returned by `beforeShowDay`. Also there is an added problem that for every day in the calendar you are sending an Ajax request.

A proposed solution can be to load all the unavailable dates at page load and use that data in the `beforeShowDay` method.

Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var dates;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'unavail_dates',
            unavaildates: '2'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            dates = data;
        }
    });

    $('#MyDate').datepicker({
        minDate: '+2',
        maxDate: new Date(2014, 1, 28),
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var string = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date);
            return [dates != undefined && $.inArray(string, dates) > -1];
        },
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
            jQuery(this).change();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your input, unfortunately i need it to update when clicked on! I agree nothing is being passed back so i suppose what i am looking for is a way to pass the var array out of the savevariable function or get the result from here into a format beforeshowday can use.

Comment: @David you need to update what when you clicks what? I'm not seeing any variable params to the ajax request so this should be fine

Comment: yes the varable will be the unavaildates: 2, i have it like this for testing. the function should pull a fresh list of unavail dates when the user clicks on the date field as other users may also have the same list of dates from when they landed on the page.